# washer draining

Tags: washing-machine

Having problems with very loud spin cycle and were told by a service worker that the bearings were being damaged. He said draining height was too high(8 ft), causing the problem, making the pump work too hard. However the manual says 96 in max. The washer is in our basement.  He said to move the washer, along with installing new water connections, and connect it to the sewer pipe on the other side of the basement for more efficient draining to alleviate the problem. Any thoughts of this or other (easier) solutions?

Comment: If you're operating at the absolute max of what the washer was designed for, I think it's reasonable that the pump will have a hard time, make more noise, and have a shortened life.

Comment: I might pump into a barrel then use a quality small sump pump like a little giant to pump up, the little Joann may cost 100$ but that saving the life on a much more expensive washing machine may be worth it.

Comment: How about a pedestal to lift the washer up a few inches?  BTW, I'm skeptical that height of the discharge is the issue but it would be easy enough to prove/disprove this as a cause.

Comment: Of course check if the noise is the pump or the main bearings on the drum.